# how to use argparser module in python to make a complex command

Tags: python, argparse

i'm trying to make a python program that has a complex argument parser .
the program (let call it MyProg ) need to work as follow

1-MyProg  wil take some files as input so i used a **-f** flage in the main parser (this is already a subparser so i can't use a subparser).

2-the program has 2 argument (**-a** and **-s**)that shoudent be present together and one of them is required so i used a mutualexclusion group.

3-**-a**  need to have a **-k** argument with it so i put the **-k** alone in a normal group inside the 
mutualexclusion group i made i the 2nd step and made it (**-k**) a required argument.

4-the problem is that the **-s** argument need either **-k** or another **--e** argument (not both) so i don't know where to put this **-e** argument so it can't be with **-a** or with **-k** .

***the code :***

```
description = "Prog"
# Initialize parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=description,)

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(required=True)

parser_MyProg = subparsers.add_parser('MyProg')


group_mut = parser_MyProg.add_mutually_exclusive_group()

group_k = group_mut.add_argument_group()


group_mut.add_argument('-a', type=int)
group_k.add_argument('-k', '--key', required=True, type=type=argparse.FileType('r'))

group_mut.add_argument('-s', type=int,)

group_mut.add_argument('-e',type=int)


parser_MyProg.add_argument( '-f', nargs='+', type=type=argparse.FileType('r'))
```

***#some valid usecases (Should be valid)***

```
args = parser.parse_args(
    'MyProg -a 8 -k k.txt  -f file1.txt file2.txt '.split())

args = parser.parse_args(
    'MyProg -s 8 -k k.txt  -f file1.txt file2.txt '.split())

args = parser.parse_args(
    'MyProg -s 8 -e 5  -f file1.txt file2.txt '.split())
```

***#some invalid usecases (Should not be valid)***

```
args = parser.parse_args('MyProg -a 8    -f file1.txt file2.txt '.split())   #need a -k

args = parser.parse_args('MyProg -s 8  -f file1.txt file2.txt '.split())    #need a -k or -e

args = parser.parse_args('MyProg -s 8 -e 5 -k k.txt  -f file1.txt file2.txt '.split())  # -k and -e can't be present together
```

in the code above i used -e in the mutual exclusion groupe but that doesent work because :
1- i can't use it with **-s** 
2- i can use it with **-k**
3- the argument **-k** is required even with **-s** argument (with **-s** i want either **-e** or **-k** not both)

i simplified the code a little so you can see the problem .
the program is an encryption and decryption and hashing program but i just wanted to make it clear that's why i  did simplify it a little.

Comment: It would be nice if we could tell at a glance what is working and what isn't.  Your end users might also like a simple fool proof `usage` as well.  Instead it looks like I'll have to spend several minutes studying your code and description to figure out that out.  Latter...

Comment: sorry but there is no error in the program excution , the problem is in the **logic** of the program so i think you need to read the description to know what i want to do. and thank ou for the fast comment anyway.

Comment: `add_argument_group` is used only for help formatting; it does not form a "any/and" group within the mutually_exclusive_group.  `argparse` does not provide that kind of logic.  Only the simple "xor" logic of an exclusive group.

Comment: Add a `dest` to the `add_subparsers` so it can format an error message.

Comment: `argument_group` and `mutually_exclusive_group` are not designed to be nested.  Due to inheritance, the commands don't raise errors, but the nesting doesn't do anything useful.  Here `-k` gets added to the `MyProg` subparser, but not to `group_mut`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage from your code (after some syntax error corrections)

```
usage: stack61332378.py MyProg [-h] [-a A] -k KEY [-s S] [-e E] [-f F [F ...]]
```

Note that '-k' is required (no []).

If I remove 'group_k' and '-k'

```
usage: stack61332378.py MyProg [-h] [-a A | -s S | -e E] [-f F [F ...]]
```

'a/s/e' form the mutually exclusive group.

Off hand, this seems to be cleanest definition:

```
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd', required=True)

parser_MyProg = subparsers.add_parser('MyProg')

group_mut = parser_MyProg.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group_mut.add_argument('-a', type=int)
group_mut.add_argument('-s', type=int)

parser_MyProg.add_argument('-k', '--key', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
parser_MyProg.add_argument('-e',type=int)

parser_MyProg.add_argument( '-f', nargs='+', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
```

with the resulting help:

```
usage: stack61332378.py MyProg [-h] (-a A | -s S) [-k KEY] [-e E]
                               [-f F [F ...]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  -a A
  -s S
  -k KEY, --key KEY
  -e E
  -f F [F ...]
```

You'll have to enforce any rules about `k` and `e` occurring with other arguments - after parsing.  `argparse` only has the `xor` of the mutually exclusive group, and the `subparser` mechanism.